# Fastest way of removing matplotlib artists from canvas embedded with wxpython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have a python program where I have several matplotlib canvases embedded into a wxpython application. One of the canvases has many crosses in it. When the user right-click in this canvas the closest cross should be removed together with everything belonging to this cross (they are linked through an unique id-tag, and there might be things in every canvas that should be removed). I want the removing (or actually the replotting) to be as fast as possible. The program is quite large so I use several threads etc.

The easiest thing to implement this is to use  `wx.CallAfter(canvas.draw)` for each canvas. However, there is a delay between the rightclick and the refresh of every canvas so I believe that `canvas.draw()` is too slow.

I saw two other functions for fast redrawing: the matplotlib functions `blit()` and `draw_artist()`. As far as I understand, `blit()` refreshes changed pixels inside some area (I used the axes bbox). I managed to get it to work with `blit()` in the sense that the program ran without crashing...but not updating what you see on the screen.

Did not manage to get `draw_artist()` to work when removing a pixel (tried using first `line.remove()`, then `draw_artist(line)` but the line was ofcourse already dead so draw_artist did not work).

Note: I called `blit()` and `draw_artist()` with `wx.CallAfter()`!

The feeling I have is that `blit()` is the best solution, but I did not manage to get it to update to the "screen-level". So my question is: **what is the fastest and most resource-saving way of removing artists from matplotlib.canvases (embedded into wxPython) without redrawing more than you need to, but still let the change propagate to the screen?**